# Undefined SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, jwt authorization in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

i was doing jwt authorization during this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X80nJ5T7YpE&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTYTEooakHchTGglSvkZAjnE&index=12). I don't know why, but my *Intellij* cannot understand what it is "HS256" in 'createToken' method. Thanks for help!

**JwtUtil.java**

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.algorithms.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Service
public class JwtUtil {
    private String SECRET_KEY = "secret";

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

I checked dependency twice and updated the 'io.jsonwebtoken' to newest, but it doesn't seem help.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    compile group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt', version: '0.9.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong import for SignatureAlgorithm.

Try this:

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
```

Instead of:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.algorithms.SignatureAlgorithm;
```